# Acción ignorada en primer click

Tags: javascript, html

Sí tengo dos etiquetas en `HTML` con id = `h3Decentralization` e id= `divDecentralization` y quiero que cuando se de click en la etiqueta `h3Decentralization` cambie la clase de `divDecentralization` (entre `decentralization1` y `decentralization2`), ¿por qué se ignora el primer click y la acción se ejecuta con el segundo click?

Mi código:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var h3Decentralization = document.getElementById("h3Decentralization");
  var divDecentralization = document.getElementById("divDecentralization");

  h3Decentralization.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (divDecentralization.className == "decentralization2") {
      divDecentralization.className = "decentralization1";
    } else {
      divDecentralization.className = "decentralization2";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.decentralization1 {
  color: red;
}

.decentralization2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="h3Decentralization">Decentralization</h3>
<div id="divDecentralization">div Decentralization</div>
```

Comment: Hola VegoDiego, bienvenido a SO en español, te recomiendo que leas el [tour] para conseguir tu primera medalla y entiendas qué es un [mcve]. Las explicaciones que has dado no son muy claras, ¿podrías añadir el código HTML al que haces referencia? puedes [edit] tu pregunta las veces que quieras para ayudarnos a ayudarte.

Comment: saca todo del evento  `DOMContentLoaded` y funcionara, pero si quieres cargar el contenido de lugar de `DOMContentLoaded` intenta con el evento `onload`, y quiza asi si funcione

Comment: He puesto el código como ejecutable y funciona sin problemas. Debes leer [mcve] y editar la pregunta para que podamos ver el problema.

Comment: He podio solucionar el problema. Al parecer lo que pasaba era que en mi documento html tenía las dos clases (class="decentralization1 decentralization2") para la etiqueta con id="divDecentralization" y eso no permitía el correcto funcionamiento del evento click. Muchas gracias a todos.